# Executing flush method, for sending mutations to accumulo without closing the writer

Tags: java, scala, accumulo

I am writing data to accumulo storage natively using [Geomesa Native Client](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/tree/master/geomesa-native-api). Here is my java code

```
package org.locationtech.geomesa.api;

import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Connector;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mock.MockInstance;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.client.security.tokens.PasswordToken;
import org.apache.accumulo.core.security.Authorizations;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.feature.AttributeTypeBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloDataStore;
import org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.AccumuloFeatureIndex;
import org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.index.AccumuloFeatureIndex$;
import org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.index.IndexMode$;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.type.AttributeDescriptor;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class WorkerBeta {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            DomainObjectValueSerializer dovs = new DomainObjectValueSerializer();
            final GeoMesaIndex<DomainObject> index = AccumuloGeoMesaIndex.buildWithView(
            "aj_v14",
            "localhost:2181",
            "hps",
            "root", "9869547580",
            false,
            dovs,
            new SimpleFeatureView<DomainObject>() {
              AttributeTypeBuilder atb = new AttributeTypeBuilder();
              private List<AttributeDescriptor> attributeDescriptors =
                Lists.newArrayList(atb.binding(Integer.class).buildDescriptor("rId")
                    , atb.binding(String.class).buildDescriptor("dId")
                    , atb.binding(Integer.class).buildDescriptor("s")
                    , atb.binding(Integer.class).buildDescriptor("a")
                    , atb.binding(Integer.class).buildDescriptor("e")
                );
              @Override
              public void populate(SimpleFeature f, DomainObject domainObject, String id, byte[] payload, Geometry geom, Date dtg) {
                f.setAttribute("rId", domainObject.rideId);
                f.setAttribute("dId", domainObject.deviceId);
                f.setAttribute("s", domainObject.speed);
                f.setAttribute("a", domainObject.angle);
                f.setAttribute("e", domainObject.error);
              }

              @Override
              public List<AttributeDescriptor> getExtraAttributes() {
                return attributeDescriptors;
              }
            }
        );

        //Inserting 
        final DomainObject one = new DomainObject(1, "AJJASsP", 12, 40, 1);
        final GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
        System.out.println(index.insert(
                one,
                gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(-74.0, 34.0)),
                date("2017-03-31T01:15:00.000Z")
            ));

            //Read 
            GeoMesaQuery q = GeoMesaQuery.GeoMesaQueryBuilder.builder()
                .within(-90.0, -180, 90, 180)
                .during(date("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), date("2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"))
                .build();
            Iterable<DomainObject> results = index.query(q);
            int counter = 0;
            for(DomainObject dm : results){
                counter += 1;
                System.out.println("result counter: " + counter);
                dovs.toBytes(dm);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        index.close();
    }
    public static class DomainObject {
      public final int rideId;
      public final String deviceId;
      public final int angle;
      public final int speed;
      public final int error;

      public DomainObject(int rideId, String deviceId, int angle, int speed, int error) {
          this.rideId = rideId;
          this.deviceId = deviceId;
          this.angle = angle;
          this.speed = speed;
          this.error = error;
      }
    }
    public static class DomainObjectValueSerializer implements ValueSerializer<DomainObject> {
        public static final Gson gson = new Gson();
        @Override
        public byte[] toBytes(DomainObject o) {
            return gson.toJson(o).getBytes();
        }
        @Override
        public DomainObject fromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
            return gson.fromJson(new String(bytes), DomainObject.class);
        }
    }
    public static Date date(String s) {
        return Date.from(ZonedDateTime.parse(s).toInstant());
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is, I need to create `index` object every time for a new insert request and call `index.close()` to reflect the same. But I can't execute `insert()` agin, once `index.close()` is called. However i will be accepting insert request from queue at very high rate and I don't want to create `index` object every time. How can i do that?

In short how i can flush writes without calling `close()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created geomesa Client class file to use geomesa natively. Below is the partial implementation of the same which shows how you can flush with `AccumuloAppendFeatureWriter` without calling to close.

```
public class GeomesaClient {
  private AccumuloDataStore ds = null;
  private AccumuloAppendFeatureWriter fw = null;
  private SimpleFeatureSource sfs = null;
  private String tableName = "";
  private FeatureStore fst = null;
  private SimpleFeatureType sft;

  public GeomesaClient(Map<String, String> dsConf) throws Exception {
    this.ds = (AccumuloDataStore) DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(dsConf);
    this.tableName = dsConf.get("tableName");

    sft = createFeatureType();
    if(!Arrays.asList(this.ds.getTypeNames()).contains(sft.getTypeName())){
      ds.createSchema(sft);
    }
    this.fst = (FeatureStore)sfs;
    this.fw = (AccumuloAppendFeatureWriter) (this.ds.getFeatureWriterAppend(sft.getTypeName(),
        Transaction.AUTO_COMMIT));
    this.sfs = ds.getFeatureSource(sft.getTypeName());
  }
  /*
        Flush with AccumuloAppendFeatureWriter
  */
  public void flush(boolean force) {
    fw.flush();
  }
}
```